# Advice on adding user stories to Masters thesis

Tags: masters, computer-science

For my masters project I utilized user stories as a means of requirements gathering. I have roughly 100 of these along with the acceptance tests to go with them.

I'm currently writing my thesis and detailing the methods I used to gather these requirements. My question is: Do I include these user stories as figures in text or add them to my appendices, or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like including large amounts of "raw" data in a thesis, paper, or any other printed medium, because it does not contribute to the main text, and if you've already summarized the essential data in the thesis, then you don't need to explicitly include the data.

That said, you do want to make the data available in *some* medium. Perhaps you can make it available as an online repository (perhaps your school allows for "attachments" or "supporting information" to be included with your thesis. You could then scan the surveys (or bundle them up into a single file if they were generated electronically, etc.) and post them somewhere that readers can access.

Comment: Yeah I like this. Perhaps give one example in text with explanation and then direct the reader to the repository where they are all available?

Answer (score 0):

To add a little bit to the nice answer of @aeismail:

In general, they should be included and referenced somehow. My general guideline to a thesis is: I want to giv the thesis to the next person working on the project and it should contain all relevant information to a) understand and reproduce all design decisions and b) proceed from that. This would include all data gathered.

In your main text, you should give one or two illustrative examples of how your user stroies look like and how they are used.

A 100 page appendix would be overwhelming. If you can consense them to ~20-30 pages (which I would not assume), you could consider them as appendix.

In my university, we usually require a CD in each thesis containing the thesis as pdf plus all source code, executable files, data used etc. This would be a perfect place for the user stories. You can reference the CD in your text.

Comment: Yeah well to be fair I could comfortably get four to a page. So that is possible.